# filter datagridview with two comboboxes using one table

Tags: c#, sql

i searched over the webs but reached with no results,nothing is giving me what i want,all having more than one table, am using a datagridview having two combobox columns 1st column have datasource isfsectionsbindingsource,value member = isfsectionName and selected value parentISfkey in properties.i have a single table containing parent and child id.
Table ISFsections : ISFsectionId,ISFsectionName,ParentISFkey

```
private void dataGridView2_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {


            for (int i = 0; i < iSFsectionsBindingSource.Count; i++)
            {
                if (e.ColumnIndex == 4 && dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Column11"].Value == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Choose 1st combobox value");
                }

                else
                {
                    cnn.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    SqlDataAdapter dabank = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    SqlCommand cmd10 = cnn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd10.CommandText = "select ISfsectionId, isfsectionName from ISFsections where ISfsectionId = @ParentISFkey";
                    cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentISFkey", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Column11"].Value);
                    cmd10.Connection = cnn;
                    cmd10.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dabank.Fill(ds, "isfsectionName");

                    dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Column23"].DataGridView.DataSource = ds;
                }

            }
            }
```

now when am clicking 1st combobox its telling me expects the parameter '@ParentISFkey', which was not supplied. and i am using it any help concerning this

Comment: You are missing the single quotes : ISfsectionId = '@ParentISFkey'

Comment: no nothing changed

Comment: Change ExecuteNonQuery to ExecuteQuery.  A Select is a Query while any other SQL is a non query.

Comment: i cant use ExecuteQuery() ;is there any other way

Comment: Why?  Doesn't make sense!!!